# Twitter Sentiment Analysis: problem in predicting

Tags: bert, sentiment-analysis

I am going to do Sentiment Analysis over some tweets. The goal is to find out which post is with and which one is against a specific topic(which tweet is saying this product is good and which on is saying that is not good).
I have about 6000 tweets for each Positive, Negative and Neutral. I have tested some models like Naive Bayes, NN, Decision Tree and Random Forest but I saw no good results.
When I refer to confusion matrix, I see that many Positive and Negative are predicted **interchangeably**. Also, when I try to add some layers (for example in NN), it is going to over-fit.
I use these models, but almost all the results are the same:

```
[(TF-IDF)] + [(Naive Bayes), (Decision Tree), (Random Forest)]

[(BERT), (Distilbert)] + [(Fully connected NN)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Convolutional Neural Networks? Even though, they were introduced for computer vision, they [proved to be effective for sentiment analysis](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.06233) as well.

You can use this [tutorial on building a CNN for sentiment analysis](https://databasecamp.de/en/use-case/bert-sentiment-analysis) from scratch, if you need.